# Warnings on startup with atomikos starter dependency

Tags: spring-transactions, atomikos

I have a spring boot application with postgresql and rabbitmq. I wanted to use a best-effort JTA transaction that contains both a postgres and rabbitmq transaction.
I have added the spring-boot-started-jta-atomikos dependency. When I start my application I receive this warning multiple times:

```
atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@99c4993: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
```

Do I need any additional configuration?

I also get this warning at startup:

```
AtomikosDataSoureBean 'dataSource': poolSize equals default - this may cause performance problems!
```

I run with the following settings, but setMinPoolSize is never called

```
spring.jta.atomikos.connectionfactory.max-pool-size: 10
spring.jta.atomikos.connectionfactory.min-pool-size: 5
```

The documentation at:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.jta.atomikos
- https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringBootIntegration

just says I can add the starter dependency. But it seems like spring boot doesn't properly auto-configure some things.

Answer (score 0):

`spring.jta.atomikos.connectionfactory` properties are for controlling a JMS connectionFactory.
You should use the `spring.jta.atomikos.datasource` properties for controlling JDBC DataSource configuration.